# OpenMote B wireless communication

Tags: communication, wireless, open-source, building-code

Is it possible to make two "OpenMote B" devices communicate with each other (through WiFi or on other frequencies), transmit and receive data?'

[image: OpenMote B]

If yes, is there an example of such code to get started?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please link to the device shown!

Comment: The OpenMote B is apparently discontinued, but it’s based on the TI CC2538, and has 2.4 GHz and sub-GHz radios so they should most definitely be able to communicate wirelessly (though probably not over WiFi). Look for CC2538 code samples…